# pandas cumsum gt result assign back to the original dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have the following `df`,

```
id    year_month    pct
10    201901        10
20    201901        5
30    201901        3
40    201901        2
10    201902        8
20    201902        2
30    201902        7
40    201902        3
```

I want to sort `pct`, and then `groupby` `year_month`; then do a `cumsum` on `pct` which needs to be `> 10`;

```
df.sort_values(['pct']).groupby('year_month')['pct'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().gt(10))
```

but it only gave me a series

```
3    False
5    False
2    False
7    False
1    False
6     True
4     True
0     True
Name: pct, dtype: bool
```

I am wondering how to get this series back to `df` as a column,

```
id    year_month    pct    non-tail
10    201901        10     True
20    201901        5      False 
30    201901        3      False
40    201901        2      False
10    201902        8      True
20    201902        2      True
30    201902        7      False
40    201902        3      False
```

Comment: `df=df.assign(non_tail=df.sort_values(['pct']).groupby('year_month')['pct'].cumsum().gt(10))` , just assign it back and get rid of the `lambda`(not required for cumsum())

Comment: a simple `df['non_tail'] = df.sort_values('pct')...` would be more memory-efficient?